# Is this correct caching?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I try to cache my userlist, so that when 200 users are online, there are not 200 database querys every 10 seconds.

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Business
{
    public class UserList
    {
        private static object locker = new object();
        public static List<DAL.OnlineList> userList;
        public static DateTime date;
    }
}
```

-

```
  public static string GetOnlineList(HttpContext con)
  {
        List<DAL.OnlineList> onlineList = new List<DAL.OnlineList>();
        if (Business.UserList.date == DateTime.MinValue || Business.UserList.date < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30))
        {
            Business.UserList.date = DateTime.Now;
            onlineList = DAL.UserDAL.GetAllOnlineUser().OrderBy(x => x.Username).ToList();
            Business.UserList.userList = onlineList;
        }
        else
        {
            onlineList = Business.UserList.userList;
        }

        //Before
        //List<DAL.OnlineList> onlineList = DAL.UserDAL.GetAllOnlineUser().OrderBy(x => x.Username).ToList();
   }
```

The method GetOnlineList is called every 10 seconds from a WebMethod / pageMethod / JavaScript-call.
So before it was: 200 Users, every 10 seconds = 200 x 10 x 6 = 12000 db-querys per minute.

Then my code is right, the first user will load the list from the database and store it - and it will be refreshed every 30 seconds - correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the condition in your code snippet needs an adjustment

```
if (Business.UserList.date == DateTime.MinValue || 
    Business.UserList.date > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30))
```

You can always use the built in caching mechanism ASP.NET that has. You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).

Basically, you have two options to cache objects with sliding expiration and absolute expiration.

With **sliding expiration** an object remains in the cache if you retrieve it sooner than the expiration timespan you have set. For example, if you set a timespan of 2 minutes and you retrieve the object every 1 minute it will remain forever in the cache.

With **absolute expiration**, an object stays in the cache based on the timespan regardless of how many times it has been retrieved.

In your example, you are have the absolute expiration logic. Here is an example on how to use it:

```
public List<DAL.OnlineList> Users
{
    get 
    {
        List<DAL.OnlineList> users = null;
        string CacheKey = "dal_users";

        users = HttpContext.Current.Cache[CacheKey];
        if ((users == null)) 
        {
            users = DAL.UserDAL.GetAllOnlineUser()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Username).ToList();
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(CacheKey, users, Nothing, 
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
                CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 on absolute expiration. `if (Cache["UserList"] != null) //USE CACHE else //DATABASE CALL` Or, you could put a loop in global.asax to update the cache every 30 seconds, then a user would never have to wait for the database to update... It would always be up to date without relying on requests to update cache.